# How to define a custom UserDetailsService with WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm a bit lost at how `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` should be correctly extended to properly use a custom `UserDetailsService` and expose it as a bean.
I mean, there are:

- `userDetailsService()`: Javadoc says:

  > Allows modifying and accessing the `UserDetailsService` from
  > `userDetailsServiceBean()` without interacting with the
  > `ApplicationContext`. Developers should override this method when
  > changing the instance of `userDetailsServiceBean()`.
- `userDetailsServiceBean()`: Javadoc says:

  > Override this method to expose a `UserDetailsService` created from
  > `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder)` as a bean. [...] To change
  > the instance returned, developers should change
  > `userDetailsService()` instead
- `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder)`: Javadoc says:

  > [...] The `authenticationManagerBean()` method can be used to expose
  > the resulting `AuthenticationManager` as a Bean. The
  > `userDetailsServiceBean()` can be used to expose the last populated
  > `UserDetailsService` that is created with the
  > `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` as a Bean. The `UserDetailsService`
  > will also automatically be populated on
  > `HttpSecurity#getSharedObject(Class)` for use with other
  > `SecurityContextConfigurer` (i.e. RememberMeConfigurer)"

If I just read this, I understand that:

- `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder)` configures an `AuthenticationManager`, which can be exposed by overriding `authenticationManagerBean()` to be marked with `@Bean`; to build this `AuthenticationManager`, `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder)` builds and wires a `UserDetailsService`
- overriding `userDetailsServiceBean()` (to mark with `@Bean`) allows to expose the `UserDetailsService` built and wired by the previous method
- if I want `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder)` to use my own implementation of `UserDetailsService`, I must override `userDetailsService()` to return it; it will be then exposed by overriding `userDetailsServiceBean()`

So I ended up with this:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
    throws Exception {
  final MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService = userDetailsService();
  auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
  // all the other configuration has been omitted
}

@Override
protected MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
  return new MyUserDetailsService();
}

@Bean
@Override
public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBean() throws Exception {
  return super.userDetailsServiceBean();
}
```

However, this is what puzzles me and what I see:

- the default implementation of `configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` substantially does nothing (just sets `disableLocalConfigureAuthenticationBldr` to `true`) and in particular it does not call `userDetailsService()`; it's my overriding that does it, so it's me that I'm injecting my custom `UserDetailsService` implementation through the use of `userDetailsService()`; in other words, if I don't override `userDetailsService()` and create the custom `UserDetailsService` instance in `configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` directly, I get the same result
- probably related to the above: the default implementation of `userDetailsService()` is exactly identical to that of `userDetailsServiceBean()`... I would have expected the latter to delegate sooner or later to the former, but if the former default implementation is actually the same... I really get lost and I wonder why two distinct methods are provided
- I would expect that, with the above, my custom `MyUserDetailsService` implementation is exposed in the application context, but if I try to inject a `MyUserDetailsService` instance somewhere else, Springs complains that there's no such instance in my application context; indeed, the bean returned by `userDetailsServiceBean()` is always some kind of delegating wrapper; if I inject a generic `UserDetailsService` instance and try to use it, I get an `IllegalStateException` saying that "UserDetailsService is required" (the delegation mechanism in `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.UserDetailsServiceDelegator.loadUserByUsername(String)` fails to retrieve a proper default `UserDetailsService`...)
- by debugging I see that `userDetailsService()` is invoked twice (hence creating two DISTINCT instances of `MyUserDetailsService`), once by the above implementation of `configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)`, and once by `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.createSharedObjects()`...

So, the above is clearly incorrect (authentication works because the right `UserDetailsService` is injected into the `AuthenticationManager`, but it fails to expose the `UserDetailsService` in the application context) and I may probably overcome all these problems by simply marking a `MyUserDetailsService` bean with `@Service` or by writing yet another `@Bean` method in my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` extension that returns an instance of my custom `UserDetailsService`, hence bypassing both `userDetailsService()` and `userDetailsServiceBean()`... But I'm not sure this is the best way to achieve the desired result (those two methods should have been put there for some reason...)

I really think `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is overly complicated in how it handles this...

Comment: Did you read the official spring docs its not as complicated as you are making it https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-userdetails

Comment: @ThomasAndolf I know what a `UserDetailsService` is, but I don't understand how your link would be relevant to what I'm asking about.

Answer (score 2):

The way to configure custom `UserDetailsService` depends on the number of`UserDetailsService`s and kind of `UserDetailsService`.

Also remember there are different ways to expose a bean in Spring: `@Configuration` with factory method (`@Bean`), `@ComponentScan` with `@Component`, XML etc.

### One global `UserDetailsService`

If you want to use one global custom `UserDetailsService` you only have to expose it, see [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.4.RELEASE/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-userdetailsservice):

> **10.10.7. UserDetailsService**
>
> `UserDetailsService` is used by `DaoAuthenticationProvider` for retrieving a username, password, and other attributes for authenticating with a username and password. Spring Security provides in-memory and JDBC implementations of `UserDetailsService`.
>
> You can define custom authentication by exposing a custom `UserDetailsService` as a bean. For example, the following will customize authentication assuming that `CustomUserDetailsService` implements `UserDetailsService`:
>
> This is only used if the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` has not been populated and no `AuthenticationProviderBean` is defined.
>
> **Example 66. Custom UserDetailsService Bean**
>
> ```java
> @Bean
> CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService() {
>     return new CustomUserDetailsService();
> }
> ```

The default implementations of `userDetailsService()` and `userDetailsServiceBean()` return the global `UserDetailsService`. There is no need to override these methods.

### Different `UserDetailsService`s

If you want to use different `UserDetailsService`s for different `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`s you could override  [`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#configure`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.4.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html#configure-org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder-):

> Used by the default implementation of `authenticationManager()` to attempt to obtain an `AuthenticationManager`. If overridden, the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` should be used to specify the `AuthenticationManager`.

and add it with [`AuthenticationManagerBuilder#userDetailsService`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.4.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/builders/AuthenticationManagerBuilder.html#userDetailsService-T-):

> Add authentication based upon the custom `UserDetailsService` that is passed in.  It then returns a `DaoAuthenticationConfigurer` to allow customization of the authentication.

The default implementations of `userDetailsService()` and `userDetailsServiceBean()` return the `UserDetailsService` of the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`.

If you want to inject the `UserDetailsService` to another component, you could  override `userDetailsServiceBean()`. If you expose more than one `UserDetailsService` you have to use different bean names.

### Built-in `UserDetailsService`

There are some built-in `UserDetailsService`s created by `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`, which are not exposed.

If you need such an `UserDetailsService` in another component, you have to override
`userDetailsServiceBean()`, see [`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#configure`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.4.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html#configure-org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder-):

> For example, the following configuration could be used to register in memory authentication that exposes an in memory UserDetailsService:
>
> ```java
> @Override
> protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
>        auth
>        // enable in memory based authentication with a user named
>        // "user" and "admin"
>        .inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER").and()
>                        .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
> }
>
> // Expose the UserDetailsService as a Bean
> @Bean
> @Override
> public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBean() throws Exception {
>        return super.userDetailsServiceBean();
> }
> ```

If you expose more than one `UserDetailsService` you have to use different bean names.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis. So, if I understand it correctly, it seems like `userDetailsServiceBean()` is used to expose the `UserDetailsService` instance used by `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` but *only if* that is implicitly built by some of the building methods (like `inMemoryAuthentication()`), while this is not true if you set your own instance with `AuthenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService`. Also, it's still not clear to me the reasoning behind `userDetailsService()` and the Javadoc that is supposed to explain it. The absolutely generic names of these methods don't really help.